# Given this HTML structure and JS function to toggle the container display, why is this not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Got this not throwing any error, but not changing the `display` either. Beginner here, so please be patient.

```js
function addEventListenerToMenuButtons() {
  const buttonContainer = document.querySelector(".features-list");

  if (buttonContainer) {
    buttonContainer.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const clickedButton = event.target.closest('.list-ul');

      if (clickedButton) {
        removeActiveClassFromAllButtons();
        clickedButton.classList.add("activeBtn");
        const buttonId = clickedButton.id;
        if(buttonId === "deliverable-tracker-btn-container") {
          showSectionContainer(buttonId);
        } else if(buttonId === "dashboard-btn-container") {
          showSectionContainer(buttonId);
          
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
function removeActiveClassFromAllButtons() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.list-ul.activeBtn');
  buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.classList.remove("activeBtn");
  });
}
addEventListenerToMenuButtons();


function showSectionContainer(sectionId) {
  const sectionContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.section-container');
  const targetSection = document.getElementById(sectionId);

  sectionContainers.forEach(container => {
    container.style.display = container.id === sectionId ? "block" : "";
  });

  if (targetSection) {
    targetSection.style.display = ""; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
  <ul class="features-list">
    <li class="features-item list-ul active" id="dashboard-btn-container">
        <div style="display:inline-flex">
          <button class="features-item-button">Dashboard</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="features-item list-ul active activeBtn" id="deliverable-tracker-btn-container">
        <div style="display:inline-flex">
          <button class="features-item-button">Deliverable Tracker</button>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="section-container" id="dashboard-container">
    <div class="card" id="active-clients-card">
      <div class="kpi">5</div>
      <div class="label">Active Clients</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="open-tasks-card">
      <div class="kpi">4</div>
      <div class="label">Open Tasks</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="overdue-tasks-card">
      <div class="kpi">2</div>
      <div class="label">Overdue Tasks</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-container" id="deliverable-tracker-container" style="display: none">
    <h1>TESTING NEW SECTION - Deliverables</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug issue?

Comment: It looks like you're comparing `"deliverable-tracker-container"` with "deliverable-tracker-btn-container" - did you debug what `buttonId` is?   I also recommend you match your variables with what they are as `buttonId` refers to the id of the `ul` not the "button"

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Are you facing any error message?

Comment: Hi, @Justinas! It actually toggles the `section-container` when setting its `display`to `none`, but not to `block`.

Comment: @NicoHaase, if changes, when `display=none`, but not back to `block`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

1. remove -btn from the id to match the div's ID

   ```
    if (clickedButton) {
      removeActiveClassFromAllButtons();
      clickedButton.classList.add("activeBtn");
      const buttonId = clickedButton.id;
      showSectionContainer(buttonId.replace('-btn',''));
    }
   ```
2. use active OR activeBtn, not both. I removed `active` from the LIs

   ```
   <li class="features-item list-ul activeBtn" id="deliverable-tracker-btn-container">

   <li class="features-item list-ul" id="dashboard-btn-container">
   ```
3. Initialise the page depending on the activeBtn

   ```
    addEventListenerToMenuButtons();
    let active = document.querySelector(".list-ul.activeBtn");
    if (active) showSectionContainer(active.id.replace('btn-',''))
   ```

```js
function addEventListenerToMenuButtons() {
  const buttonContainer = document.querySelector(".features-list");
  if (buttonContainer) {
    buttonContainer.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const clickedButton = event.target.closest('.list-ul');
      if (clickedButton) {
        removeActiveClassFromAllButtons();
        clickedButton.classList.add("activeBtn");
        const buttonId = clickedButton.id;
        showSectionContainer(buttonId.replace('-btn',''));
      }
    });
  }
}
function removeActiveClassFromAllButtons() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.list-ul.activeBtn');
  buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.classList.remove("activeBtn");
  });
}
addEventListenerToMenuButtons();
let active = document.querySelector(".list-ul.activeBtn");
if (active) showSectionContainer(active.id.replace('btn-',''))

function showSectionContainer(sectionId) {
  const sectionContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.section-container');
  const targetSection = document.getElementById(sectionId);
  sectionContainers.forEach(container => {
    container.style.display = container === targetSection ? "block" : "none";
  });
  if (targetSection) {
    targetSection.style.display = ""; 
  }
}
```

```css
li.activeBtn { background-color: red }
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
  <ul class="features-list">
    <li class="features-item list-ul" id="dashboard-btn-container">
        <div style="display:inline-flex">
          <button class="features-item-button">Dashboard</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="features-item list-ul activeBtn" id="deliverable-tracker-btn-container">
        <div style="display:inline-flex">
          <button class="features-item-button">Deliverable Tracker</button>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="section-container" id="dashboard-container">
    <div class="card" id="active-clients-card">
      <div class="kpi">5</div>
      <div class="label">Active Clients</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="open-tasks-card">
      <div class="kpi">4</div>
      <div class="label">Open Tasks</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="overdue-tasks-card">
      <div class="kpi">2</div>
      <div class="label">Overdue Tasks</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-container" id="deliverable-tracker-container" style="display: none">
    <h1>TESTING NEW SECTION - Deliverables</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```